# Getting ReactCSSTransitionGroup to work for a fade in transition with React.js

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a simple landing page that I want to add a transition effect to.  I am using React for my view rendering.  I want to have a button fade in and out based on certain states:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
                              <div className="button-row">
                                  <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Request Invite</a>
                              </div>
                              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

CSS:

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

However, when I run this, the transition does not work.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does work, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5Luz6ym/). I've enlarged the transition duration of `.example-appear` and changed the transition of `.example-enter` which you can see after clicking any links.

Note that `.example-appear`, which is triggered in `componentDidMount()`, has effects on the first rendering of mounted component ; `.example-enter` on the other hand has effects on newly rendered children components.